# My e.KeyCode == Keys.Add is writing in the textbox focused

Tags: c#

I have this code in a windows form that calls a function that calculates a number:

```
private void KeyDown_Accion_Teclas(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{    
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Add || e.KeyCode == Keys.Oemplus)
    {
        cmdAlta_Click(sender, e);
    }
}
```

But in any textbox that is focused or selected, when I press the `+` button to call the function, its writes the symbol of `+`.

I only want to call the function but not to write the `+` symbol. Nothing I've tried has worked.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please specify more details about the code? For example, you need to show the event handler inside which the above if statement is written. That'll help contributors help you with your problems.

Comment: Hi Yatin, of course, in the form, the event handler is this code:`this.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.KeyDown_Accion_Teclas);`

Comment: Try adding: `e.SuppressKeyPress = true; e.Handled = true;` as the first two lines in your `if` block (assuming this is in the `KeyPress` event of the `TextBox` control)

Comment: See here for a documentation of how to handle key events at the form level: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-handle-keyboard-input-at-the-form-level. Pay attention to the details explained there about how to setup this correctly ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void KeyDown_Accion_Teclas(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{    
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Add || e.KeyCode == Keys.Oemplus)
    {            
        cmdAlta_Click(sender, e);
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
}
```

Or maybe:

```
private void KeyDown_Accion_Teclas(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{    
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Add || e.KeyCode == Keys.Oemplus)
    {            
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        cmdAlta_Click(sender, null);
    }
}
```